# How to disable external css stylesheet - Newbie

Tags: html, css

I have created a three page web page and I'm using an external css stylesheet that is adjusting my navigation lists so they go across the top and have a coloured background.

When I try and create a list on a page within a table the indenting and vertical listing don't work.
I traced the issue to the external style sheet.

How do I go about turning off the settings the stylesheet did so I can properly format the list?

**[EDIT- Okay, so I did a work around. I removed the external stylesheet link as was suggested and put all the style info into my head.  Then I did a div around the ul and another around the li which seems to half way gotten it working.  Around the li I set the width:50px and that got my vertical listing working. The  list-style-type:square still doesn't do anything but I'm too fed up to care anymore for tonight.]**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Elex267-Webpage</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="myStyle.css">
</head>

<body>
<!-- Banner at Top of Page ***********************************-->
<div style="background-color:blue; color:white;font-size:30px;">

<img src="Pics/camosun-white.png" alt="CamosunPNG" width="200" height="70" align="left">
<div align="center"style="margin-left:50%">Elex 267 Web Demo
<br>
Microchip TCP/IP Stack v3.02</div>
</div>
<!--*********************************************************-->
<!--NavBar Code *********************************************-->
<ul>
<li><a href="index.htm">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="features.htm">Features</a></li>
<li><a href="about.htm">About</a></li>
</ul>
<!--***************************************************-->
<h1>
Welcome to the features page of the website.<br>
</h1>
<p>
This web page is being run on the NM101 NorthMicro Pic Prototype Board with the LCD/Keypad and Network modules.
<br>
Features are:
</p>
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td>
<p>This is a paragraph</p>
<p>This is another paragraph</p>
</td>
<td>This cell contains a table:
<table border="1">
<tr>
 <td>A</td>
 <td>B</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>C</td>
 <td>D</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>This cell contains a list
<ul>
 <li>apples</li>
<li>bananas</li>
<li>pineapples</li>
</ul>
</td>
<td>HELLO</td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>

<!-- And the External CSS Stylesheet Code -->

 p {color:black;font-size:20px;background-color:white;}
 body {background-color:white;}
 ul{list-style-type:none;margin:0;padding:0;overflow:hidden;}
 li{float:left;}
 a{display:block;width:400px;background-color:#ff0000;color:white;}
 a:hover,a:active{background-color:#cc0000;}
```

Comment: Remove the reference to the external stylesheet.

Comment: If I do that then the nav bar becomes a vertical list.

Comment: You either want the stylesheet or you don't. You can't have it both ways.

Comment: Your layout is horrible (tables). Kill it as fast as you can.

Comment: Yup, layout does suck. It was a mandate to demo that we "know" that you can put other things into a table other than just data. I gather using tables for layout is an old school slap-dash method of formatting and that using CSS has superseded that for the ease of output manipulation. Heck, the only reason I'm using an external style sheet is because I read it was the preferred method. I certainly wasn't taught that in class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just read your edit, and while it seems you're gone I am going to answer anyway. Don't give up. CSS can be frustrating to troubleshoot and troublesome to implement in the beginning. Inline styles, font tags hell it all seems ever so much easier, until you realize the actual power that CSS gives you over your styling. I think what you should do is step away from your work for a little bit and do some reading on CSS so you're better understanding what it is you're doing, I'm going to give you a couple of tips here that should help with the issues at hand, but I still think you need to read more.

- Get the styling OUT of the head and back into an external style sheet, that is the worst advice you could have possibly been given.
- Read up on specificity first. That is how CSS decides which rule applies if there are conflicting rules. For example take this code:

  ```
  a{color:blue;text-decoration:underline;font-weight:bold;}
  p{color:red;}
  a{color:green;font-weight:normal;}
  ```

Your links are going to turn out green, underlined and normal weight. This is because the green and normal weight came after the blue and bold in the order of how it was read, this is the simplest of the rules, there are others like is it inline, is it an id or a class etc. Read the rules and you'll understand how to write your CSS to get the rules to apply where  you want them. This is where the terrible "put it in the head" advice came from because that CSS will be applied after external CSS. Still doesn't make it the right way to do it.

- Learn about Classes and ID's. Just quickly ID's are unique names you can apply to elements for example  you could then style just that ID in your CSS with #mainNav{color:blue} the thing to remember about ID's is they are UNIQUE. Do not use 5 UL's with the ID of mainNav (the main reason for this is so you can use them to identify them, say in js or jQuery for example). If you have multiple things that need the same styling you use classes, the nice thing about classes is you can chain them so for an easy example consider the following code:

```
.blue{color:blue}
.underlined{text-decoration:underline}
.bold{font-weight:bold}
```

Seems sort of dumb on first reading but now look at how you could apply that.

```
<p class="bold blue">This is some blue text<span class="underlined"> some of it is underlined</span> and some of it isn't</p>
```

This is where you need to look to solve your problem. If you wanted to apply those list styles just to your nav, adding a class would solve it cascading to other lists. See the following:

```
.nav ul{list-style-type:none;margin:0;padding:0;overflow:hidden;}
.nav li{float:left;}
.nav a{display:block;width:400px;background-color:#ff0000;color:white;}
.nav a:hover,a:active{background-color:#cc0000;}

<div class="nav">
   <ul>
       <li></li>
   </ul>
 </ul>
```

Any other lists you create wouldn't take on those styles. Basically you want your external style sheet to start with your basics then get more specific as you go. So the styles you want on every list go at the top and go on the ul and li or ol and li elements, then as you go further down the sheet you can get more specific.

**Stay away from inline CSS
Stay away from CSS in the head**

Trust me, learn to do it right and you'll be so happy you'll never understand why you did it any other way. Make use of the Chrome inspect element to trace down why something is displaying a certain way and then fix the CSS, forget these hack ways of fixing it. Fix it right.

Comment: CSS in combination with a tabular layout will make your head explode spectacularly. He should be reading about decent layout solutions before trying to go into more advanced topics in CSS.

Comment: From experience I honestly wish specificity had have been one of the first things I read about CSS, but yeah you're right, honestly I didn't read his layout since it seemed pretty irrelevant to his problem. Just the CSS >.<

Comment: OMG, you taught me stuff.  Thanks.  Yes I need to read more and bought a SAMs book on it last night. If only the instructor would have done something like this instead of saying go off to this online tutorial and then create this web page example. Guess what, next week we're doing a lab on JavaScript because we've already learned all we need about HTML and CSS. WTF! Aaaaaaaarrrrggggghhhhh!!!!

Answer (score 0):

If i know what your asking, you cant do that.

You can inspect with firebug/chrome dev tools and find the properties which are being overwritten.

Once you find them you can then overwrite in your own stylesheet.

Keep in mind that specificity is important here as well.

If it does not work you may need to add weight to your selectors, or use the !important keyword.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to retain the styles in the sheet, just keep it from affecting the list on the page? Why not give that list a particular ID and style differently?

For example, I just called your list #cellul and gave it a 10px margin to demonstrate the different styling:

```
p {color:black;font-size:20px;background-color:white;}
body {background-color:white;}
ul{list-style-type:none;margin:0;padding:0;overflow:hidden;}
li{float:left;}
a{display:block;width:400px;background-color:#ff0000;color:white;}
a:hover,a:active{background-color:#cc0000;}
#cellul{list-style-type:none;margin:10px;padding:0;overflow:hidden;}
```

Here's the result: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Koubenec/rgnk5/2/)

Comment: Your link showed the list of fruit as being all on one line. I want the default of one fruit each line with a dotted indent.

Comment: Ok how's this? Elements are on different lines and have bullets. However, the bullets were added in the list items themselves so it's a little hacky...http://jsfiddle.net/Koubenec/rgnk5/19/

Answer (score -1):

You can set a class for your `<ul>` like so:

```
<ul class="sth">
```

Then in the CSS stylesheet, put your class name afterthe `ul` like:

```
ul.sth {list-style-type:none;margin:0;padding:0;overflow:hidden;}
```

Comment: This answer is wrong. `.sth ul` would match a `<ul>` within an element with a class name of `.sth`. You're looking for `ul.sth`.